# UITabBar: How to connect an item to a view controller?

Tags: ios, uitabbar

**I am NOT using a UITabBarController.**

I have a view controller and I added a `UITabBar`, it has two items.

How can I make sure that when the first item is clicked, it loads the content from a specific view controller, and when another item is clicked, loads the content from another view controller?

Comment: how u added the tab bar ? code or storyboard ? show some code of what you tried

Comment: @Mr.T i add the tab bar by drag and drop. i don't have code for it, i just can say that i make an outlet for the uitabbar, and then for that instance, i set the delegate, and i can catch that the item in the uitabbar is being clicked but my issue is that i don't know how to load a view controller when an item inside the uitabbar is clicked. i don't face that problem normally with uitabbarcontroller, but now i am facing it because i am using just uitabbar

Comment: did u connect the view controller to the tab bar item ?

Comment: Curious - what you describe is exactly what `UITabBarController` is for. Why not use one?

Comment: @rmaddy because i want the uibar to be in the top, now i am still with the problem any hep please?

Comment: @Mr.T yes you can't make a segue

Comment: help please guys, i am out of solutions

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers ([Detect when a tab bar item is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837475/detect-when-a-tab-bar-item-is-pressed)), You should implement the UITabBarDelegate protocol.

Once you're implementing this protocol, just use the 
`- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item` method to know when a user changes the selected item of a tab bar. implement this method, and you will have to check which item is selected, and manually change your view's content based on that.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the `delegate` of the `UITabBar` to be the `UIViewController` and the `UIViewController` needs to conform to the `UITabBarDelegate` protocol and implement the method

**Swift**

```
optional func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didEndCustomizingItems items: [UITabBarItem], changed changed: Bool)
```

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didEndCustomizingItems:(NSArray<UITabBarItem *> *)items changed:(BOOL)changed
```

You can find details in the [`UITabBarDelegate` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/)

Comment: did you even read the question ? ? ? ?? this has nothing to do with the content that iwant to load

Comment: @sarah excuse me for trying to help. I don't really feel like my not understanding which thing you were unsure of deserves a down vote. Yes, I read your question, it's not very clear. For example, why aren't you using a UITabBarController? I thought you were asking about how to receive tap events from the UITabBar. I guess I don't understand at all what your trying to do. Can you explain what the desired end result would be?

Comment: first of all, it's not me who downvote, i don't have a good reputation to downvote. second, i've my reasons why i don't want to use UITabBarController. third, if you didn't understand my question, i guess it would be better to make a comment and then i would explain more. fourth. i am asking about how to load a view controller when a user clicks on the tab

Comment: What do you mean by "Load a view controller"? If you want you can just present one view controller from the other. If you're in a navigation stack you can push a view controller onto the stack (http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UINavigationController/pushPop.html). If you're in a container view controller you can swap out the displayed view controller (https://www.objc.io/issues/1-view-controllers/containment-view-controller/). Outside of those options I think if neither works you might not be understanding UIViewControllers correctly. If you can give more details that would help.

Comment: I can't present a view controller completely, because that would mean i show a completely new view controller, what i want is when a user clicks on a tab bar item, a view controller shold be shown **inside** the view controller that has the tab bar. think of it as uitabbar controller, when u click on a bar item, a new content show **inside** the same view controller

Comment: You need to use a container view controller, read the Objc.io article https://www.objc.io/issues/1-view-controllers/containment-view-controller/ and you should find your answer.

Comment: please don't u have a swift version ? that language for me is like Spanish :) :) i don't understand nothing