# Add a button in a Tab Bar like the Vinted app

Tags: ios, swift

I want to know how the Vinted app (I take it as an example) went about displaying a View Controller by clicking on an item in the Tab Bar. As if we were making a simple link with a new view.

Example video :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qmy9o0q02uxkf43/2017-10-26%20T19-55-30.mp4?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your own TabBar and implement `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method: `didSelectViewController`

and then you have opportunity to detect tap.

[This post would be perfect for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33842706/2069114)

Comment: Instead of posting an answer with a link to another answer, vote to close the question as a duplicate if appropriate.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I was able to do what I wanted to do except for a little problem: I have to do something wrong.

When I press the item in question where I want to display my VC, the one appears behind and then opens it to me a second time with the transition show.

An idea ?

Answer (score 0):

1. They could be using something custom, not a `UITabBar`
2. `UITabBar` has `UITabBarDelegate` which can tell you when a tab is selected.

In both of these cases, they could just create the new view controller programmatically and present it.