# Where do I implement the UITabBarControllerDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a `tabBar` that is implemented programmatically. I would like to be able to track if the user press a certain `tabBar` item (or button or whatever it's called). As far as I understand, this is done by inheriting from the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` class.

If I implement the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` code in one of the classes that the `tabBar` items navigates to, the `didSelectViewController` method works:

```
@interface ExperiencesContainerViewController () <ContainerProtocol, UITabBarControllerDelegate>
@implementation ExperiencesContainerViewController

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSLog(@"PRESS");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;

}
```

Now this works, but it works a bit too well as it triggers not only when I press the item of this particular `class` but whichever item I happen to press, even though those items navigate to a completely different class.

I would like the `method` to trigger only when I press the `tabBar` item of this particular class. And then I guess I would replicate this pattern in the other `classes` as well and have those methods trigger only when their respective `tabBar` item is pressed.

I read this:

[Detect when a tab bar item is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837475/detect-when-a-tab-bar-item-is-pressed)

And the answer suggests that I should implement the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` in the `class` that handles the setup of the `tabBar`. I tried that but then the `method` isn't triggered. I think this has to do with the `delegate` suddenly being set to a `class` that is not associated with one of the `tabBar` items.

Let me know if there is additional information you need or if you need to see some more code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the link you already posted has the right [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33842706/5928931) for you.

You need to make the class that handles the setup and show of the the `tabBar` implement `UITabBarDelegate`, **not** `UITabBarControllerDelegate`. Then you can use the right delegate method to retrieve when an item of the tabBar is clicked and check if it's then one you're interested in.

The method you want is `tabBar:didSelectItem:`
(sent to the delegate when the user selects a tab bar item).

More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbardelegate?language=objc).